# Embeded PHP/MySQL Implementation

Tags: php, mysql, windows, wamp

I'm writing a voting app for my school using PHP/MySQL. I've currently tested it on a WAMP server and everything is working.

The central PC to be used is already running WAMP. This will make my app vulnerable since the root admin can just enter the database and change values.

I found out that I can package it as an app that has its own embedded PHP/MySQL. I found one solution called Klone, but that is only for linux. I'd want to be able to do this in windows

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You want to implement new WAMP stack (from scratch) just because admin will see the database? WOAH. You know, that he'll be able to do that REGARDLESS of chosen technology unless you encrypt the whole hell of it?

Comment: hash the values so if a total is changed you will know as the hash will not match, and log all votes.  You could even set up a database dump that uploads/emails you every hour/day.

Comment: I'm concerned he might change the values. He actually supports on of the candidates

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want nobody else but you to see/change/has access to database table where you have voting scores saved.

Comment: So where should I store the hash? I initially thought of the mail, but it's on a local network using Wifi @cmorrissey

Comment: My concern is with change. @broadband

Comment: Hashing would be one possibility, but if I am root (or on windows administrator) I can see the code that does the hash i.e. which hash is used sha256, md5, ... and which salt, and I can still change the values. Only possibility would be to send/dump whole database to some private space which only you can access it like cmorrisse mentioned. The you can compare data from two sources and if they are equal ...

Comment: You have to be able to trust your system/network administrators. Obviously we don't know the layout and politics of your school, but can you set the computer up in a cupboard somewhere that your administrator cannot get to? You need to be aware of fire hazards, of course. Don't bother "implementing [your] own version of PHP/MySQL" - that will be just as vulnerable as WAMP; even with complex passwords, MySQL can be restarted without authentication, long enough to reset the root password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that implements a new php/mysql stack as a standalone app independent of the existing stack. http://www.server2go-web.de/